# Can you turn a declarative sentence into a interrogative sentence with changing pronunciation type or way of tone?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, spoken-english

Looks like you can change a declarative sentence to interrogative by changing your way of speech. I have come across this several times, What do you think?

> Hey man, How's it going?
> -Hey fine, And you?
> -Oh, You know. You're meeting the boss? -Yeah

Its a part of The Son movie [20:11/20:19]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Statements used as questions in casual speech.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9730/statements-used-as-questions-in-casual-speech) See also [What is it called when a grammatical statement is delivered as a question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/333790/what-is-it-called-when-a-grammatical-statement-is-delivered-as-a-question)

Comment: Helpful but I'm still curious about other opinions.

Comment: I doubt you'll get "other opinions" here - questions asking for *opinions* are inherently off topic. If there's something *specific* you want to know that's not covered by one of those two earlier questions, you can edit your question to explain the issue in depth.

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion - it is a known fact.

Comment: I know what you mean, obviously you didn't understand mine. People describe knowledge by their opinions. And when I say other opinions I mean I'm searching for that knowledge, I'm not here for discussion.

Comment: This topic may seem repetitive and useless to you, but it is new for me. I apologize for the way I write, I always express things philosophically and that's not good I know.

Comment: If there is no answer, I will naturally delete it and ask another way or use other sources